# What is the difference between "volus"+infinitive and conditional mood?

Tags: verbs

E.g. the sentences

- mi volus salti.
- mi saltus.

both mean something related to wanting to jump. What is the difference between these two forms?

Comment: Actually, just one of those phrases means something related to wanting to jump. _Mi saltus_ doesn't necessarily mean _I would want to jump_ or _I want to jump_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Mi volus salti* only states that I would want to jump, but not that I necessarily would do so.

*Mi saltus* means that I would jump, not just want to but actually do it (in whatever the context is).

- *Mi saltus sur la tegmenton de nubskrapanto por savi vin!*
  (I would jump onto the roof of a skyscraper to save you!)
- *Se li enirus la ĉambron, mi volus elsalti tra la fenestro!*
  (If he entered the room, I'd want to jump out the window!)
- *"Sed kion vi farus, se leono aperus nun?" "Kompreneble, mi simple saltus en la aŭton!"*
  ("But what would you do, if a lion appeared now?" "Of course, I'd just jump into the car!")
- *Se mi estus en la supra etaĝo de brulanta domo, mi certe volus salti tra la fenestro. Sed eble mia fobio de altaĵoj malebligus tion.*
  (If I were in the upper story of a burning house, I'd certainly want to jump through the window. But perhaps my fear of heights would prevent that.)

Comment: Isn't _If I were in the upper story_ supposed to be _If I were in the upper floor_ (or _If I were on the upper floor_)?

Comment: @kiamlaluno I usually hear "story", but "floor" is another term for it; which term is more common may depend on where you are. (And with "floor" you would be on and not in it (at least as far as I've heard)).

Answer (score 3):

*Mi volus salti* on its own means "I would like to jump", which is a weaker form of "I want to jump." It suggests either that you probably won't jump, or that your statement is a request that you be allowed to jump. See [PMEG](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/gravaj_verboj/povi_devi_voli/us.html) for discussion of this use of *volus* without a condition.

*Se mi sidus sur varma forno, mi volus salti* means "If I were sitting on a hot stove, I would want to jump."

*Mi saltus* means "I would jump." Presumably a possible situation has just been mentioned.

Comment: _Mi volus salti_ seems more like _I would want to jump_.

Comment: Yes, when a condition is supplied. See the 2nd paragraph.